# How to have bash aliases usable from any directory?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash, shell, bash-alias

As title sais I want to be able to use bash aliases from inside directories other than home. If file structure looks something like /home/Documents, do I have to create another .bash_aliases folder from inside the Documents directory but point those to the bash file saved in the home directory?

For reference, .bash_aliases exists in the home directory

```
alias mover=". ./mover.sh"
```

and I have a mover.sh in the home directory as well

Comment: If mover.sh only exists in your home dir, then define the alias as such: `alias mover='. "$HOME"/mover.sh'`

Comment: To combine the two comments, the alias `mover=". ./mover.sh"` works in all directories but `mover.sh` (presumably) doesn't exist in all directories so your alias needs to reflect a path that works regardless what directory it is being called from could be relative to your `"$HOME"` directory or an absolute path.  Keep in mind if the alias is shared between users then `"$HOME"` will be user dependent (which can be good or bad thing depending)

Comment: In general, if your "alias" is simply a script, why not just put it in your path?  Also, you can substitute `~` with all of the `$HOME` refs you see here because this is all being done within the context of bash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some ideas below that are based on the post
[How to set an alias on a per-directory basis?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/52997/how-to-set-an-alias-on-a-per-directory-basis)

If the aliases are contained in a file named `.aliases` in all
directories, one idea would be to define your aliases as:

```
alias "foo=. ./.aliases; alias-command"
```

Another idea is to add the following function to your `.bashrc` file,
so that every time that you `cd` to a directory with an `.aliases` file,
it will get source'd:

```
function cd () { 
  builtin cd "$@" && [[ -f .aliases ]] && . .aliases
}
```

Comment: I like the `cd` function, but I'd remove `return 0` -- if the directory does not exist, the function should have a useful exit status.

Comment: @glennjackman: Good idea - I removed it.

Answer (score 0):

> alias mover=". ./mover.sh"

... will always look for `mover.sh` in the current working dir
*(cwd, the place you last did `cd` to, as printed by `pwd`)*

Example; replace that with

`alias mover=". $HOME/mover.sh"` or
`alias mover=". ~/mover.sh"`

*Not tried, both might/should work regardless of cwd; I'll be lazy and leave them so.*

Answers to questions like this
can be found by study of the content of the "Bash guides" at http://www.tldp.org